# Do you know any reason to use Apache instead of Nginx?

Tags: apache, nginx, webserver

Do you know any reason to use Apache instead of Nginx? I'm talking about a "new project" with no any legacy code or configuration.

updated:

Most popular reasons to use Apache are:

- we have our rewrite config
- we have our application, working on Apache

..it is OK for legacy app. But what about absolutely "new app 2013"?

What do you think?

BTW, I know about topics:

- [Nginx and Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540669/nginx-and-apache)
- [Nginx vs Apache or using Apache with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046160/nginx-vs-apache-or-using-apache-with-nginx)
- [Nginx v Apache for high traffic sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171992/nginx-v-apache-for-high-traffic-sites)
- [Use Nginx or Apache for serving dynamic content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582016/use-nginx-or-apache-for-serving-dynamic-content)

..and I can't find any pro for Apache there. Could you point me?

Comment: Can you make your questions more specific? These types of questions are usually discouraged. See the SO FAQ for details on acceptable questions: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: This is question is very common and deep theoretical by nature. Could you be more specific? Seems like You know some pro and con. Do you?

Comment: Read the FAQ, the fact that someone else down voted your question (not me) confirms that another is agrees with my comments. If you googled "Apache vs. Nginx" you could find your answers, and use SO for questions about the finer points. That's really the purpose of SO.

Comment: One reason to use Apache is the wealth of modules and plugins if you need them.

Comment: Wich modules for nginx do you think are missing? Could you be more specific?

Comment: I switched to *nginx* and am not looking back. Reliability, speed, intuitive configuration, etc...

Comment: One of the design goals of nginx was to improve configuration scaling. Many apache configuration directives are position dependent; as it grows it becomes more difficult to maintain. Nginx can have the same problem if one tries to translate an apache config line by line to nginx. This scaling problem can be overcome by using a few nginx tips described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWRYbLKsS0I) by the author, Igor Sysoev.

Answer (score 28):

Apache is still the most popular web server on the Internet, [estimated](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/category/web-server-survey/) to serve about 55% of all websites in existence, compared to nginx's 12% (in Jan 2013).

**UPDATE (Apr 2015):** Apache still has the largest share at about 40%, and nginx has grown to 15%. Check the above mentioned link for the latest figures.

**UPDATE (Jul 2020):** nginx has comfortably surpassed Apache in popularity at 37% vs 25%. Apache still has more hits on searches.

It is the oldest web server around, which means that you won't have any trouble finding people skilled in configuring it.

You're also slightly more likely to find help when searching the web. SO has ~80,000 tags for Apache, and ~40,000 for nginx.

Installation documents sometimes assume you're using Apache, often including .htaccess documentation, but not the equivalent nginx configuration:

- [Yii 1.0 was only tested with Apache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.0/en/quickstart.installation)
- [Yii 1.1 only has clean URL instructions for Apache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x)
- [CodeIgniter 2.0 only has .htaccess instructions for Apache](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/urls.html)
- [CodeIgniter 3.0 still only has .htaccess instructions for Apache in the clean URL section](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)
- [The Drupal setup page has notes for Apache and IIS, but nginx is only mentioned in the comments, and at least one person is having trouble getting the nginx settings working](https://www.drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls#serverconfiguration)

My recommendation? Either are perfectly good choices, flip a coin if you can't find any compelling reasons either way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you know any technical reasons?

Comment: I dispute your assertion that "ease of use and maintenance" is not a technical reason.

Comment: Honestly, if you'd like to try nginx, try it out for the next small project you're building. Big projects are generally when you want to stick to technology you already know and understand - you don't need the extra overhead of learning a brand new tech.

Comment: Gustav, You are right! But I mean something like: FastCGI module of nginx has no such key features..

Comment: As far as I'm aware, nginx has no missing key features.

Comment: What are some of the "Standard installation documents" you're referring to here?

Comment: I've seen a number of web based system installation documents that cover Apache settings. CodeIgniter, Yii, Drupal, Wordpress, PHP, etc.

Comment: [CodeIgniter 2.0](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/) and [CodeIgniter 3.0](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/) don't specify a specific server. [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.apache-nginx-config) and [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/requirements/webserver) treat the servers equally. [Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx) has extensive support for both out of the box. [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.php) has equal docs for many servers, not just these two. With all due respect, I believe your assertion to be incorrect.

Comment: On the contrary, lots of documentation (including several of the ones you mentioned) still makes the assumption that you are using Apache, only including .htaccess information without the equivalent nginx rewrite config. I've added examples to my answer.

Comment: I don't think rewrite documentation is a fair point to use to compare the two servers as Apache's mod_rewrite is significantly more complex than Nginx's rewrite module. Nginx did have the advantage of hindsight seeing the one way rewrite is used by almost everyone so they didn't have to be as complex. Specific to .htaccess, Nginx makes a point not to use per-directory configuration because of its [performance burden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466120/using-htaccess-file-in-apache) (up to a 50% performance reduction comparing Apache with to Apache without in my personal benchmarks).

Comment: Anyway, I obviously won't convince you :) Thanks for considering my points. I don't think it's productive to continue this little debate so I'll stop. I do respect your points, I just respectfully disagree.

Comment: Any reasons left for 2020? :)

Answer (score 13):

Feb 2018 response here.

Apache is 47.4% (-3.3% 1 year), Nginx is 36.8% (+4.4% 1 year)

The trend is linear, by 2020 if nothing happens, Nginx will be the most used.

Nginx was made for supporting lots of concurrent requests, which modern apps usually do, like small Ajax requests, and less full page loads.

I've seen Benchmarks ( for a static resource), and Nginx MURDERS Apache, both in requests per seconds and RAM usage.

I've realized all this an hour ago, I’ve been using apache for lots of years, and I’m migrating just after writing this post.

Conclusion for 2018: Go for Nginx.

Bench:[dreamhost Web-server-performance-comparison](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215945987-Web-server-performance-comparison)

Share:[w3techs.com web_server](https://w3techs.com/technologies/history_overview/web_server)

Share 2: [netcraft.com web-server-survey](https://news.netcraft.com/archives/category/web-server-survey/)

Comment: This is off-topic, but ```by 2020 if nothing happens``` feels like a round-house kick in the head.

Comment: @Chaos Haha, I'm sorry english is not my primary language, how would you phrase it?  "if nothing happens, by 2020" ?

Comment: oh your English is fine (yeah, maybe a comma would help but I didn't even notice that). I was talking about the PTSD I got from 2020 being a year of the pandemic.

Answer (score 9):

There really aren't any ***objective*** reasons to use Apache over Nginx.

In fact, there may actually be [performance reasons](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/71610/nginx-vs-apache-are-there-any-actual-usage-comparisons-and-statistcs-out-there) why Nginx is superior. These sorts of reasons however are usually of no significance when putting an entire web application in perspective.

You will find many ***subjective*** reasons to prefer one web server over the other, such as bias related to familiarity. With respect to web servers, these biases might be tied to a user's age since Apache has been around much longer. For many of these users, learning a new system is not a productive use of time. For less experienced or new administrators, familiarity bias is not applicable.

Another subjective reason is the mis-belief that a larger market share will always yield recognizably greater levels of support. These reason fails to recognize the diminishing relevance of larger market share past extreme points of acceptance. For example, a recent [Netcraft survey](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2014/10/10/october-2014-web-server-survey.html) has Nginx up to 14.42% market share of all web sites while Apache is at 37.45%. While one may blindly assume Apache to have superior support given its substantially larger percent of market share, the fact is the 14.42% represents *one hundred forty eight million, three hundred thirty thousand, one hundred ninety websites* (148,330,190). That's an extraordinarily massive number of websites and users which and who are running on Nginx. The raw number of users of Nginx is so large that it's relatively smaller market share will have no recognizable difference in support level.

Answer (score 7):

For those looking for main differences/comparison:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I can add a bit to the first answer.

The stats for Apache market share overall are true, but you can consider the question in more detail. NGINX has the greatest share of the top 1000 websites and the top 10,000 websites, and it's neck and neck for the top 100,000 websites. http://w3techs.com/technologies/cross/web_server/ranking

So figure out which tranche of usage you expect your website to fall into, and use that to find the most relevant market share information.

To learn more about NGINX, there's an upcoming "official" O'Reilly book. Free preview for download here: http://www.aosabook.org/en/nginx.html

Answer (score -1):

apache mod_php is much more stable and cleaner while nginx will often deliver HTTP Bad Gateway error coded in 502.

Comment: Embedding PHP is not "clean," IMHO. The only reason it's so popular is because it allows for web hosts to stuff a thousands websites on an single server. Your 5xx errors are probably due to poor configuration, not Nginx's limitations.

Comment: what does nginx has in common with php :D?  it's just adressing you to your streams who serves php... why you need mod_php when there's php-fpm, which support multi-threading? i mean how much more legacy can you hold on and ignore a properly coded products for very flexible usage like php-fpm, nginx and others..??