# things to consider before site goes live

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Morning. I have finished my first site, which will be going live soon.

There's a lot of PHP and therefore I have been working/testing on xaamp/apache.

I just wanted to confirm exactly what will happen to my links once the site goes live - most of them contain no http:// prefix and are simply 'home.html' or 'about_us.php'.

I assume apache automatically inserts the localhost prefix once I click on a link, so will this be the same when the site goes live? And for pics etc I currently just have something like the following.

```
<img src="img/logo.png">
```

Will this suffice?

One more thing - I am pretty sure (obviously I will check!) that some PHP header locations include the localhost prefix - I presume this will need to be removed?

Many thanks.

Comment: http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2287002/Website-Launch-Checklist-25-Things-to-Test-Before-Your-Site-Goes-Live

Comment: Make sure in your .htacess file, the `ReWriteBase` is correct, that's important for detecting base directory.

Comment: Yes, they are relative urls, and are completely valid, also `localhost` prefix is not required

Comment: Relative links like your img tag above are fine. Remove all references of localhost from php header locations, links, img src, etc.

Comment: I would upload it to a "test" directory or sub-domain first, http://mydomain/test for instance, and test really quick, and then if everything works fine, rename the directory, or move to root.

Comment: why don't you do a test with a sample website with little html, css, image, php code and see how that goes?

Comment: thanks guys, very helpful (and the answer I was looking for as I didn't fancy going through every link adding a prefix!)

Comment: what type is your host ? if you have clean www.domain.com and simple hosting it should be fine. but if there are sub folders and so .. prepare for reworking most of the links.

Comment: Make it live but hide it from everyone except you `(.htaccess)` and test it without fear. There are dozens of free shared hosts for testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache has nothing to do with it. The *browser* handles resolution of incomplete URLs.
There are three kinds of relative URLs, which all resolve relative to the URL you're currently on. For the examples below, assume you're on `http://example.com/abc/xyz.html`:

- relative URLs like `foo/bar.jpg` resolve to `http://example.com/abc/foo/bar.jpg`
- absolute paths like `/foo/bar.jpg` resolve to `http://example.com/foo/bar.jpg`
- protocol relative URLs like `//example.com/foo/bar.jpg` resolve to `http://example.com/foo/bar.jpg`

Comment: Use the `//` if you want external resources to be pulled in via https if your site is on https but can also be in http. That saves you the check. If you are ignoring external resources when your page can be http and https your users will get a browser warning that the page is not secure. For ecom that might be critical.

Answer (score 1):

Relative links will work, you don't have to explicitly prefix your website name, if you go with that, you have to change the name every time your domain name changes.

You need to optimize the website. Follow these simple steps:

1. Minify Javascript and css files.
2. If there is no need avoid using htaccess for performance. Using .htaccess files slows down Apache. If you can, modify the main server config file (usually called httpd.conf)
   [.htaccess performance hit](https://muffinresearch.co.uk/avoiding-the-use-of-htaccess-for-performance/) , [Using .htaccess file in Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466120/using-htaccess-file-in-apache)
3. Compress Javascript and css files.
4. Include Meta and title tags.
5. Avoid using frames if possible.
6. Validate Your HTML Code

**Follow this excellent article for more information:**

[Web optimization tips best practices](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ultimate-guide-to-web-optimization-tips-best-practices/)

[Optimize Your Website](http://www.wikihow.com/Optimize-Your-Website)

Comment: my javascript files are really very lightweight. I will look into minifying the CSS though.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely things to consider before you let your website live:

1. Let all your links be in `absolute path`, which is full url of your file or link
2. Confirm you have changed your `database host`, `username`, `password` and `database name` to the server's one
3. Make sure you have your homepage url changed from `development environment` to http://firstsite.com/
4. `error_reporting();`
5. Manage error logs and log paths
6. Look for your first `echo`. Not even a white-space before any change in header information
7. Prevention of `SQL Injections`
8. Don't just let your login information to easy like `admin` / `admin`